# How can I filter a dataset in Delphi on a TDateTime field

Tags: delphi, datetime, filter

I have a dataset that I need to filter by time.  e.g. I want records where the time contained in a TDateTime field is between 6:00 AM and 6:00 PM.

My dataset contains a field named time_of_day, of type TDateTime.  The value assigned to the filed is a time, with no date.

I have tried creating the filter string using both the string representation of the time (`time_of_day >= '6:00 AM' and time_of_day <= '6:00 PM'`), and also using the floating point representation (`time_of_day >= 0.25 and time_of_day < 0.75`), but neither have worked.

I need to know how to construct the filter string to assign to the TDataSet.Filter property.

Comment: Not sure if this is relevant to your case, but you could also consider changing the SQL that produced the dataset (unless you want the discarded records for some other purpose).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think it might depend on short time format but this works for me using TADODataSet.

```
ADODataSet1.Filter := 'TimeField = 11:00:00';
ADODataSet1.Filtered := True;
```

A more full proof solution is to use the OnFilterRecord event instead.

```
procedure TForm4.ADODataSet1FilterRecord(DataSet: TDataSet; var Accept: Boolean);
begin
    if DataSet.FieldByName('TimeField').AsDateTime = FilterValue then
        Accept := True
    else
        Accept := False
end;
```

If you need interval it would look like this.

```
ADODataSet1.Filter := 'TimeField >= 10:00:00 and TimeField < 11:00:00';
ADODataSet1.Filtered := True;
```

OnFilterRecord

```
procedure TForm4.ADODataSet1FilterRecord(DataSet: TDataSet; var Accept: Boolean);
begin
    if (DataSet.FieldByName('DateField').AsDateTime >= FromTime) and
         (DataSet.FieldByName('DateField').AsDateTime < ToTime) then
        Accept := True
    else
        Accept := False
end;
```

If you use AMPM notation you need to enclose the time in `'`

```
ADODataSet1.Filter := 'TimeField >= ''10:00 AM'' and TimeField < ''11:00 AM''';
ADODataSet1.Filtered := True;
```

But I would really recommend the OnFilterRecord instead so you do not have to worry about time formats.

Comment: For the OnFilterRecord, I'd prefer `Accept := <FilterTest>;` instead of the if..else. Good answer, though. :) I'll give you a +1 for the thoroughness alone (and I have answer to this question too).

Comment: My filter expressions are generated dynamically, based on user input, so the OnFilterRecord event isn't practical.  The number of conditions and types of operators vary significantly.  After receiving your answer, I did change my filter to use the ShortTime format, and it did correctly.

Answer (score 2):

`TDateTime` in Delphi is type double, where the integral portion is the number of days since 12/30/1899 and the fractional (decimal) portion is the time.

A time of noon (without a date portion) would be indicated as 0.5, which means that 6:00 AM would be 0.25 (exactly, 1 day / 24 hours * 6 hours) and 6:00 PM would be 0.75. The simplest way to filter, then, would be:

```
// 6 hours after midnight
Frac(YourTimeField.AsFloat) >= (1.0 / 24.0) * 6 and
// 18 hours after midnight
Frac(YourTimeField.AsFloat) <= (1.0 / 24.0) * 18;
```

Doing the actual calculation makes sure that if the number can't be exactly represented as 0.25 (like 0.2499999999999), you still get the correct value to compare.

`Frac` returns the fractional portion, just to make the code clearly indicate that you're only considering the time portion of the value.

Comment: I understand that will work as executable code, but can I use the Fract function in a filter string for a dataset?

Comment: No. You can use it in the OnFilterRecord event. What database are you using? There might be a better way than filtering.

Comment: I'm actually using kbmMemData

Answer (score 0):

I don't use ADO but Zeos, but rendering as float

```
  xx.filter:='datefieldname > '+floattostr(strtodatetime(edit1.text));
```

works for me.